# Netty ChannelFuture.operationComplete() not getting invoked on IOException

Tags: netty

I'm testing my client server handling during connection failure.

On the Client side my ChannelFuture (below) is not getting invoked when I unplug the LAN cable when sending a message from client to server.
What I expected was the exception would get caught by my ChannelFuture so I could deal with it in operationComplete.

Instead it is only getting caught in the last upstream handler in the client's pipeline. 
Am I doing something wrong? Or maybe this is an issue with Netty 3.2.4?

The Exception I'm getting in the handler when I unplug the LAN cable:

```
    java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:25)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:198)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:166)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:243)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:321)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:280)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:200)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

My ChannelFuture:

```
    ChannelFuture future = Channels.write(channel, message);
    future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {

           @Override
           public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
               if (!future.isSuccess()) {
                   LOG.error("Client failed to send message", future.getCause());
                   future.getChannel().close();
               }
           }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

From the stack it seems like the write was complete successfully. The Exception was thrown while it tried to read from the channel. If you are interested in this kind of Exceptions you will need to implement your own SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler and override the exceptionCaught(..) method.

Be sure to add the handler to the ChannelPipeline.

Comment: If I do the following sequence:
1. Add breakpoint before Channels.write
2. pull LAN cable
3. Allow Channels.write and addListener to run

Then only the UpstreamHandler.exceptionCaught() gets triggered the ChannelFuture does not.

The message gets lost and the server doesn't recieve it.